# Debian 10 apt-key issues

Tags: debian

I just had a really hard time getting apt to add the repository key to a fresh install of Debian 10.

After much trial and error, I discovered that the following steps work:

```sh
wget https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2017.gpg.key
sudo apt-key add qgis-2017.gpg.key
```

When I tried the commands listed on the install page, I got this error:

```sh
gpg: key 51F523511C7028C3: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
```

Also, note that I only had success with the 2017 key; not the 2019 one.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue. 
Did not get it working in 2019 key install instructions. Worked with the 2017 key but that key will expire soon: 2019-08-16. In my case an Ubuntu docker 18.10 install (see my Dockerfile beneath). Although I still have same key errors (as above) with 2017 key apt-get update works with 2019 version it does not. Seem to be related to 2019 public key not yet present.
Kind regards, Remco

```
    FROM ubuntu:18.04

    RUN apt-get update 
    RUN apt-get install -y gnupg ca-certificates wget

    RUN echo 'deb     https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
    RUN echo 'deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list

    # Not working
    # RUN wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key | gpg --import
    # RUN gpg --fingerprint 51F523511C7028C3
    # RUN gpg --export --armor 51F523511C7028C3 | apt-key add -
    # Error message InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45

    # Working (for now)
    RUN wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2017.gpg.key | gpg --import
    RUN gpg --fingerprint CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45
    RUN gpg --export --armor CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45 | apt-key add -

    RUN apt-get update 
    RUN apt-get install -y qgis python3-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Answer (score 1):

For avoiding key error in Debian 10, complete sequence of commands (as superuser) is as follow:

```
wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2017.gpg.key | gpg --import
gpg --fingerprint CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45
gpg --export --armor CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45 | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get update
```

I precisely discovered it in this reference: https://www.gis-blog.com/how-to-install-qgis-3-on-ubuntu/

It worked for me.

**Editing Note 1:** With an unsolved key error, QGIS 2.18 will be installed instead.

**Editing Note 2:** I ran again all commands and you can observe my successful result:

```
zeito@debian-pc:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for zeito: 
root@debian-pc:/home/zeito# wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2017.gpg.key | gpg --import
--2019-08-10 21:02:33--  https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2017.gpg.key
Resolving qgis.org (qgis.org)... 104.27.139.220, 104.27.138.220, 2606:4700:30::681b:8bdc, ...
Connecting to qgis.org (qgis.org)|104.27.139.220|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1944 (1,9K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                   100%[===================>]   1,90K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-08-10 21:02:35 (26,4 MB/s) - written to stdout [1944/1944]

gpg: key CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45: "QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2017) <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
root@debian-pc:/home/zeito# gpg --fingerprint CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45
pub   rsa2048 2017-08-16 [SC] [expires: 2019-08-16]
      61E0 A086 749E 463E DE50  2255 CAEB 3DC3 BDF7 FB45
uid           [ unknown] QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2017) <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>
sub   rsa2048 2017-08-16 [E] [expires: 2019-08-16]

root@debian-pc:/home/zeito# gpg --export --armor CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45 | sudo apt-key add -
OK
root@debian-pc:/home/zeito# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [39,1 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [46,8 kB]          
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Sources [27,3 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [56,6 kB]
Hit:6 https://qgis.org/debian buster InRelease                           
Get:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Translation-en [31,6 kB]
Fetched 201 kB in 8s (26,6 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
root@debian-pc:/home/zeito#
```

Comment: I’ll try that on a clean install and see if it works. Regardless, it appears that the instructions on the web site do not work on Debian 10.

Comment: It worked for me yesterday on a clean install!

Comment: Please, see my second 'Editing Note'.

Answer (score 1):

Because of plugin incompatibilities I had to downgrade QGIS from the recent stable version (3.8) to the ltr version (3.4) ... and faced the sames issues above as described with the 2017 key.

**Solution**
*System: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic*

There is a 2019 key available now! The method described on [linuxhint](https://linuxhint.com/install-qgis3-geospatial-ubuntu/) works but you need to use the new key like this

```
sudo vim  /etc/apt/sources.list   
#Add to sources for Stable version (3.8)  
deb https://qgis.org/debian bionic main

#Add to sources for LTR version (3.4)  
deb https://qgis.org/debian-ltr bionic main

wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key | gpg --import
gpg --fingerprint 51F523511C7028C3
sudo gpg --export --armor 51F523511C7028C3 | apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis
```